# Can I use FindBy to filter data assosiated with ManyToOne relationship?

Tags: symfony, many-to-one, findby

Can I use FindBy to filter data associated with a ManyToOne relationship ?
For example...

> Car Entity:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Klient", inversedBy="nip")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fk_klient", referencedColumnName="nip")
 */
private $fkKlient;
```

> Action in controller:

```
    $userKlientNip = '22222222';
    $cars = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AdminBundle:Car')->findBy([
        // 'fkKlient.nip' => $userKlientNip
        //...
    ]);
```

If I run FindBy with an empty array, my twig dump will look like this:

[image]

Basicaly I want to get only cars with fkKlient.nip == 22222222 (in this example)

Comment: I think QueryBuilder is the better way to achieve what you want : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Answer (score 0):

What does this return:

```
$userKlientNip = '22222222';
$cars = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AdminBundle:Car')->findBy(
    array('fkKlient.nip' => $userKlientNip),
);
```

I'm not certain of your entities, so I'm not sure if this is the answer. Try it.

Comment: It would return:

Unrecognized field: fkKlient.nip
500 Internal Server Error - ORMException

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty sure it's "can't do thing"... but I finely worked it out... 
So basically, 'fkKlient.nip' is not a key (no surprise there), but when I refer to the actual key and compare it against $userKlientNip as it is, (Example 1) it will magically do what I was looking for.
Also, I could define the value as an associative array and I would get the same result (Example 2).

**Example 1 - Action in controller:**

```
    $userKlientNip = '22222222';
    $cars = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AdminBundle:Car')->findBy([
         'fkKlient' => $userKlientNip
    ]);
```

**Example 2 - Action in controller:**

```
    $userKlientNip = '22222222';
    $cars = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AdminBundle:Car')->findBy([
         'fkKlient' => ['nip' => $userKlientNip]
    ]);
```